# Logic Error with printf() on string in c

Tags: c

Commenting out `printf()` seems to give me a segmentation fault. I tried searching for answers but nothing came out :/

```
char *var_name(char *data)
{
    char *trash, *nawa;
    int i=0;

    trash = strsep(&data,"\"");
    nawa = strsep(&data,"\"");
    printf("<br><br>%s",nawa);
    if(vname==NULL) return data;

    data = val_eater(data);
    //printf("here is: %s",data);

    return data;
}

char *val_eater(char *data)
{
    int a=0;
    while(1) {
        if (data[a] == '\n' || data[a] == '\r' || data[a] == ';' )  { 
            a++;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    data = &data[a];
    return data;
}
```

[Image of the code snippet(.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCDUo.png)

The return value of `val_eater()` should be a pointer pointed to the nearest value of the string that is not `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `';'`.  I'm using `printf()` to see if it does the job (and yes, it does) but when I tried removing the `printf`, it produces a segmentation fault.

Comment: `if(vname==NULL) return data;` : `vname` not initialize and not assignment.

Comment: What a pass, what to expect what kind of output?

Comment: The code assumes that the input string has two double-quotes in it, and will behave very badly if it doesn't.

Comment: Although `strsep` will change the `data`, Do  `val_eater` expect what kind of input?

Comment: hi i made some editing. val_eater should expect a pointer not necessarily the one returned by strsep (in this case, the pointer *data)

edit: but yes i know that strsep changes the pointer *data